# In tableau, How do I summarize the data on IDnum , but for each IDnum show the latest version of the name?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I want to select the latest name of each IDnum.

Below is a sample of the data set

- IDnum  Date  Name  Income
- A1  Jul-20  James  $30;
- A1  Aug-20  James   $10;
- A1  Sep-20  JamesSt $30;
- B1 Jul-20 AliceB $70;
- B1 Aug-20 Alice__Be $20;
- B1 Sep-20 AliceBet $10;

I want to summarize the data on IDnum , but for each IDnum show the latest version of the name

- A1 JamesSt $70;
- B1 AliceBet $100;

How can I do this in Tableau?calculated field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works:

```
IF DATE = {FIXED [IDnum]:MAX([Date])} THEN [Name] END
```

Comment: Hello Andy it worked. Perfect. I had to wrap your query into another field.  {fixed [IDnum] : MAX (andys query) }